# Docker daemon error on joining swarm node - could not find local IP address - unknown port

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, networking

Consider the following setup:

Three hosts in the same network:

- Host A - SLES
- Host B - Ubuntu
- Host C - Ubuntu

Then, the following has worked:

- Init swarm on A
- Join swarm at B, make B a manager

The following is however not working:

- Join swarm at C as worker with token issued from A
- Join swarm at C as worker with token issued from B

In both cases we get the same error:

```
Error response from daemon: could not find local IP address: 
dial udp: address udp/2377​: unknown port
```

Honestly, I have even no idea how to interpret this message.

Any ideas?..

UPD. nmap results for ports 2377,4789,7946 (hint from Felipe in a comment below) - no idea what are they good for but now it is clear that something is wrong with host C.

**Host A** (Primary manager)

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
2377/tcp open   unknown
4789/tcp closed unknown
7946/tcp open   unknown
```

**Host B** (Secondary manager)

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
2377/tcp open   unknown
4789/tcp closed unknown
7946/tcp open   unknown
```

**Host C** (should become a worker)

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
2377/tcp closed unknown
4789/tcp closed unknown
7946/tcp closed unknown
```

**Host D** (successfully added as a worker)

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
2377/tcp closed unknown
4789/tcp closed unknown
7946/tcp open   unknown
```

Finally, with host B there is the actual problem.

- swarm init => OK; port 2377 is open
- swarm leave => port is closed again
- swarm join => error "port not found"

Comment: UPD https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34794

Comment: Maybe if you share the commands you have used, like - (...) docker swarm init --advertise-addr x.x.x.x (...) - (...) docker swarm join (...) We might have a clue. Maybe the ports configurations for host C are wrong ?

Comment: the command is exactly same copy-paste which is issued by docker itself on "docker swarm join-token worker"

Comment: @Peter did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try the commands above between all hosts ?

INSIDE HOST A:

```
nc -zv HOST_B_IP_ADDRESS 2377,4789,7946
nc -zv HOST_C_IP_ADDRESS 2377,4789,7946
```

INSIDE HOST B:

```
nc -zv HOST_A_IP_ADDRESS 2377,4789,7946
nc -zv HOST_C_IP_ADDRESS 2377,4789,7946
```

INSIDE HOST C:

```
nc -zv HOST_A_IP_ADDRESS 2377,4789,7946
nc -zv HOST_B_IP_ADDRESS 2377,4789,7946
```

As explained in https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/#open-protocols-and-ports-between-the-hosts, some ports must be available between hosts in order for Docker Swarm to work correctly.

The error reported sounds like a port related problem. 
Maybe is there another application in one of these hosts already using one of the ports needed by Docker ? Maybe a firewall configuration ?

Comment: So your command says "invalid port" so I tried nmap with these ports - see update above.